# SQL exclude rows from table based on parameter

Tags: sql, t-sql, parameters, case, case-when

I have a table of data, and would like to create a case when based on the following parameter:

```
DECLARE @FY_Ending INT
SET @FY_Ending = 2020
```

If `@FY_Ending` is < to 2020 then take the column named Code

If `@FY_Ending` is >= 2020 then take the column name Code but drop where LA_Code in (810,811)

(Note: Code is just a column of different numbers and 2 would like to be excluded from 2020 onwards)

How would I go about writing this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql should look like this

```
select Code from Table where (@FY_Ending < 2020) or (@FY_Ending >= 2020 and LA_Code in (810,811)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select code
from your_table
where (@FY_Ending < 2020 and LA_Code in (810,811))
   or @FY_Ending >= 2020
```